# Proving that $S_n$ is generated

Tags: abstract-algebra

How would I prove that $S_n$ is generated by $ \{\ (1,2)(1,2,3...n) \}\ $?

I can visualize it and sort of 'feel' it, but I'm not sure how I'd prove it.

Comment: Show it for all transpositions. Why is that enough?

Comment: You may know that $S_n$ is generated by all $(i\,i+1)$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Show that $S_n$ is generated by all the transpositions, so if you can get every transposition from $(12)$ and $(1...n)$ then you're done. First express $(1...n)^{-1}$ in terms of $(12)$ and $(1...n)$. Now, show $(1...n)(12)(1...n)^{-1} = (23)$ and similarly obtain $(i,i+1)$ (the comma is there only for clarity). Can you get all transpositions from there?

Comment: Okay just lead me on a bit. I understand that a transposition is a decomposition of a disjoint cycle, in other words just exchanging 2 elements and keeping others fixed. I realize that every permutation can be written as transpositions.

However $S_n$ are ALL permutations so we are looking for ALL transpositions to these. What do you mean when you say "Composing the two a few times"?

Comment: How would I express these in terms of (12)(12...n)? That's my problem.

Comment: How would you express $(1...n)^{-1}$ in terms of $(12)$ and $(1..n)$? Hint: you don't need the first one.

Answer (score 0):

By transpositions, Julien Clancy is referring to elements of the type: (ab), that is, elements of length two.  For example, in $S_{3}$, (12)(123) = (1)(32) = (32).  Now generalize this notion to $S_{n}$.